# group by using entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Hi all I am having a sql query which I would like to execute the same using entity framework and bind it to gridview can some one help me. This is my query

```
SELECT Technology,[Description], Technologies.TechID, COUNT(*) AS 'num_employees'
FROM Technologies
LEFT JOIN Questions   
ON Questions.TechID = Technologies.TechID
GROUP BY Technologies.TechID, Technology,[Description]
```

How can I convert the same to get the results using EF

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would make this a stored procedure instead, and import it into EF.  Then you would just call it in your code and databind the result to your grid.

This way the joining, grouping, etc all happens server side instead of client side.  Otherwise, you'd be sending a lot more information than necessary to the client.  Plus, the server can theoretically do these operations faster than a client's.

Comment: yeah i too just got that idea ;)

Comment: Yeah, I usually feel "dirty" when I make a stored procedure that doesn't have any parameters and is just a fairly simple return.  I suggest beefing it up with some parameters so you feel better about making it a sproc.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i didn't have the time to test it both for logic and syntax. You need something similar.

```
var q = from a in context.Technologies
    join b in context.Questions
    on a.TechID equal b.TechID into j1
    from j2 in j1.DefaultIfEmpty()
    group j2 by new { a.TechID, b.Technology, b.Description into grouped
    select new { Tecnology = grouped.Technology, Description = grouped.Description, Count = grouped.Count() }
```